# Expo Eas Build on Android Error on Run Gradlew: react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem in expo build after starting to use EAS, and I can't solve it. The error only happens for the Android build.

The build goes through almost all the steps, however, when it reaches "Run gradlew", after a few lines, the following problem appears:

```
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found
/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-70-jsc.aar
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:buildReleasePreBundle'.
[stderr] > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
[stderr]    > Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
[stderr]      Required by:
[stderr]          project :app
[stderr]       > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
[stderr]           - generalReleaseRuntimeElements
[stderr]           - mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements
[stderr]         All of them match the consumer attributes:
[stderr]           - Variant 'generalReleaseRuntimeElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
[stderr]               - Unmatched attributes:
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]           - Variant 'mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
[stderr]               - Unmatched attributes:
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'mlkitRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]                   - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
[stderr]         The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
[stderr]           - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]           - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]           - Variant 'generalReleaseApiElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]           - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]           - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr]           - Variant 'mlkitReleaseApiElements' capability SoftWeb:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
[stderr]               - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
[stderr]               - Other compatible attribute:
[stderr]                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 23s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I've already tried changing react-native-reanimated versions, started a new project, followed several tips, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Note: the project was not ejected.

Can you help me please? Has anyone ever experienced this?

Thank you!

Comment: I have this exact same problem, really hoping someone else can figure out an answer because I can't.  I have tried pulling in the react-native-reanimated v3.0.0-rc.10 upcoming release candidate, but that didn't help unfortunately.  I have looked around for info on this but no one seems to have a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @RenéGustavo I had to remove Expo from my project as I couldn't find a solution to this problem, I feel a little disappointed in Expo